# TypeScript: How to use internal interface within namespace

Tags: typescript, module, namespaces

I have an interface that I only want to use within a namespace (internal module) and it should not be used outside the namespace.

**Example interface:**

```
namespace Test {
    interface IInterface {
        getId(): number;
        getName(): string;
    }
}
```

Unfortunately I get an error when I try to implement this interface within the same namespace if I don't export the interface (which I don't want to).

**Implementing class:**

```
namespace Test {
    class Implementer implements IInterface {
        private location: Location;

        public getId(): number {
            return 1;
        }

        public getName(): string {
            return "implementer name";
        }
    }
}
```

Which gives: *TS2304: Cannot find name 'IInterface'.* in 'Implementer.ts'.

Notice the private member of type 'Location' which is also a new type/class defined by myself in the same namespace and that is the actual reason for using namespaces because the type 'Location' already exists in the global space.

**Class with conflicting name if used outside namespace:**

```
namespace Test {
    class Location {
        private name: string = null;
        constructor(name: string) {
            this.name = name;
        }
    }
}
```

Additionally: I'm not using any modules and I'm converting some types from JavaScript to TypeScript classes. Using the `/// <reference path="IInterface.ts" />` helper doesn't work (and is not the problem here). I also don't want to introduce any module loader.

So how do I use my interface in the same namespace without exporting it?

Comment: Maybe related: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/39827281/modules-vs-namespaces-what-is-the-correct-way-to-organize-a-large-typescript-p/39827997#39827997

Comment: The other question doesn't mention internal interfaces or the accessibility of interfaces within names paces or modules

Comment: Yes, but if you start a new project, maybe you should consider to switch to modules. It's just a suggestion. :)

Answer (score 3):

I answer first to the last question: "Class with conflicting name if used outside namespace". A [global object `Location`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Location) already exists in the browser. You can use this name for your class in a module or in a namespace. Otherwise, you'll have to choose another name.

Then, you want to split a namespace. Just `export` the member `IInterface` in order to expose it outside the IIFE:

```
namespace Test {
    export interface IInterface {
        getId(): number;
        getName(): string;
    }
}
```

## Explanation

From [the handbook](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/namespaces-and-modules.html):

> Namespaces are simply named JavaScript objects in the global namespace.

Here is an illustration (see the code [in the TS Playground](http://www.typescriptlang.org/play/#src=namespace%20Test%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20export%20let%20name%20%3D%20%27abc%27%0D%0A%7D%0D%0Anamespace%20Test%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20let%20message%20%3D%20%27Hello%2C%20%27%20%2B%20name%3B%0D%0A%7D%0D%0A)):

```
namespace Test {
  export let name = 'abc'
}

namespace Test {
  let message = 'Hello, ' + name;
}
```

After the compilation, here is the JavaScript code:

```
var Test;
(function (Test) {
    Test.name = 'abc';
})(Test || (Test = {}));

var Test;
(function (Test) {
    var message = 'Hello, ' + Test.name;
})(Test || (Test = {}));
```

The namespace `Test` is a *"simply named JavaScript object in the global namespace"*. You can observe that the variable `message` couldn’t be reused outside its IIFE. Even if we create a third IIFE for the same global variable (namespace) `Test`.

Comment: First export will make the interface accessible outside the namespace or module so that is unwanted. The problem of a name that already exists should not be handles by renaming my own object. Namespaces and modules are mainly there to solve this problem.

Comment: @Huupke, I added an explanation.