# Unable to import typescript models, Property does not exit on type typeof and reference errors

Tags: typescript, module, tsc, tsconfig

I'm trying to create a microservice using NodeJS, Hapi, and typescript.  I have a basic route set up that *was* working, but I can't get my service created and imported using the directory structure that I want.  That structure is basically:

```
/server.ts
/tsconfig.json
/packages.json
/Services/
         /CarService.ts
         /BoatService.ts
/Models
         /Car.ts
         /Boat.ts
/Tests
/Bundle
```

I'm trying to separate my models from my business logic.  One of my services looks like:

```
module Services {
    export class CarService {
        saveCar(data: any): boolean {
            return false;
        }
    }
}
```

but also looked like this:

```
class CarService {
    saveCar(data: any): boolean {
        return false;
    }
}
export {CarService}
```

I've been trying to import this service into my server.ts

```
import CarService = Services.CarService;
let _carService = new CarService();
```

but it looked like this when I for the second version of `carService`

```
import * as _carService from './Services/CarService';
```

and I was trying to use the servcie like this:

```
server.route({
    method: 'POST',
    path: '/Cars/',
    handler: function (request:any, reply) {
        _carService.saveCar(request.payload);   // the error is here
        //_carService["saveCar"](request);
        reply("we did it!");
    }
});
```

The first method was giving me this error:

> Property 'saveCar' does not exist on type 'typeof CarService'.

The second method compiles in visual code but is giving me this error:

> ReferenceError: CarService is not defined

My tsconfig:

```
{
    "compilerOptions": {
        "module": "commonjs",
        "moduleResolution": "node",
        "outDir": "bundle",
        "target": "es5",
        "noImplicitAny": false,
        "sourceMap": true,
        "declaration": true
    },
    "filesGlob": [
        "./**/*/.ts"
    ]
}
```

So obviously my modules aren't compiling right.  I don't know if the error is related to the tsconfig module resolution strategy or the output directory. I've fiddled with those settings too.  I know from reading the documentation that the module resolution strategies look in a `/src/` folder first, but at one point I had a `rootDirs' array in my tsconfig.json that pointed to my`/Models/`and`/Services/` directories that I thought would solve that issue.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `export default` in `CarService.ts`, then import the class in `server.ts`:

```
// Services/CarService.ts
export default class CarService {
    saveCar(data: any): boolean {
        return false;
    }
}

// server.ts
import CarService from './Services/CarService';
let _carService = new CarService();
```

See also:

- The article *[ES6 In Depth: Modules](https://hacks.mozilla.org/2015/08/es6-in-depth-modules/)* from Mozilla;
- [Modules vs. Namespaces: What is the correct way to organize a large typescript project?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39827281/modules-vs-namespaces-what-is-the-correct-way-to-organize-a-large-typescript-p/39827997#39827997)

Comment: I was so sure I had tried every combination, ugh.  Thanks.