# Importing a module breaks local types with Property does not exist on type

Tags: typescript

I have an enumeration called `CarType`, which is in a file called `CarType.ts`. The code is as follows:

```
namespace MyProduct.Search {
    export enum CarType {
        Sedan = 0,
        Wagon = 1,
        Cabrio = 2,
        /* etc */
    }
}
```

In another file, called `SearchMain.ts` in the same directory, I have the following code:

```
/// <reference path="../../d.ts/jquery.d.ts" />
/// <reference path="../../d.ts/knockout.d.ts" />
/// <reference path="../../d.ts/fullcalendar.d.ts" />
namespace MyProduct.Search {
    export module SearchMain {
        export function Init() {

             /* snip */
             let type: CarType = CarType.Sedan;

        }
        /* snip */
    }
}
```

The above works fine, until I try to import a Full Calendar type. As soon as I add the following line, beneath the `/// reference` lines

```
import { EventObjectInput } from 'fullcalendar/src/types/input-types';
```

CarType becomes unavailable. The Intellisense error is `Property 'CarType' does not exist on type 'typeof Search'`.

How can I use the EventObjectInput from Full Calendar with my code?

Answer (score 1):

This is a confusing one:

Typescript has internal modules or namespaces, identified by the keywords `namespace` and `module`. **Those two keywords have the same meaning.** Which is the confusing part, since `module` doesn't actually mean a JS module.
Namespaces are basically just syntactic sugar for implementing the "revealing module pattern". This the type of stuff we used to do before we had actual modules in javascript, and it's usage is discouraged.

I recommend looking at Typescript playground to understand what the `namespace` keyword actually does when it's transpiled to javascript. [(example)](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play/#src=namespace%20foo%20%7B%0A%20%20const%20notExported%20%3D%204%3B%0A%20%20export%20const%20exported%20%3D%205%3B%0A%7D%0A%0A%0A%2F*%20let's%20imagine%20this%20is%20some%20other%20file%20*%2F%0A%0Anamespace%20foo%20%7B%0A%20%20export%20const%20anotherExport%20%3D%20exported%20%2B%201%3B%0A%7D%0A%0A%0Afoo.anotherExport%20%3D%3D%3D%206%3B%20%2F%2Ftrue%0Afoo.notExported%3B%20%2F%2Ferror)

Basically, `namespace` just creates an object, where you can control what is seeing outside the object. Another property is if you have two namespace declarations, with the same name on the same scope, the declarations are merged. 
But at the end of the day it's implemented as just another variable in the transpiled javascript.

Typescript also has "real" modules, also called external modules. Real modules meaning they are isolated, and you need some sort of mechanism to load them at runtime. It could be webpack or browserify, it could be `require` function if your code is meant to run in node.js, could be reuqire.js library, but you need something.

Any file that has **top-level** `export` or `import` statements is a module. (export inside namespace is not top-level!)

So, we have two options:
1. a file is not a module.
2. a file is a module.

If a file is not a module, every variable/type declared in the file is declared on the global scope.

If a file is a module, every variable/type is scoped just to that file.

So, once you added:
`import { EventObjectInput } from 'fullcalendar/src/types/input-types';`
you turned your `SearchMain.ts` into an **external module**. And now the namespace `MyProduct.Search` in `SearchMain.ts` is isolated, defined in a different scope then the one defined in `CarType.ts`. So you get your error.

---

TL;DR - what you can do?

It's very annoying to mix internal modules and external modules. Pick one.
It's greatly recommended to use just external modules. Don't use namespace, just import and export statements. It might take a while to migrate the code, but it's worth it.

The other option is to continue using `namespace`. Don't `import` `EventObjectInput`. Make it available on some other namespace. But again, it's not recommended.

---

[for more info from Typescript documentation](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/namespaces-and-modules.html)

[related stack overflow answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44493381/namespaces-vs-modules-vs-typings-in-typescript)