# Cannot find name inside namespace

Tags: node.js, typescript, namespaces, es6-modules

I'm trying to separate interfaces and implementations inside typescript, so I choose to use `module` feature. However, I always receive `Cannot find name` even when I use `<reference path=.../>`. Here is my code:

IUserService.ts

```
namespace Service {
    export interface IUserService {
        login(username: string, password: string): void;
    }
}
```

UserService.ts

```
/// <reference path="./IUserService.ts" />

namespace Service {
    export class UserService implements IUserService {
        constructor() {}
}
```

Then tsc always complains that `Cannot find name IUserService` inside UserService.ts. I follow what the documentation said about namespace but it's not working for me. What should be the fix for this?

Comment: But where is the bad tutorial that persists to teach `///` includes and `namespace` in 2019?

Comment: That's the official tutorial [here](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/namespaces.html)

Comment: Your code will be executed on a browser or on Node.js? If this is the browser, do you use Webpack or Require.js or another tool?

Comment: This will be executed on node.js.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Two advices [from the TypeScript handbook](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/namespaces-and-modules.html#pitfalls-of-namespaces-and-modules):

- Do not use the `/// <reference ... />` syntax;
- Do not use namespaces and modules together. Node.js already provides modules, so you don't need namespaces.

Here is a solution:

```
// IUserService.d.ts
export interface IUserService {
    login(username: string, password: string): void;
}

// UserService.ts
import { IUserService } from "./IUserService";
export class UserService implements IUserService {
    constructor() {
    }
    login(username: string, password: string) {
    }
}
```

You'll have to define [a `tsconfig.json` file](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/tsconfig-json.html). The `/// <reference ... />` statement is replaced by a configuration file (tsconfig.json) [since TypeScript 1.5](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/typescript/announcing-typescript-1-5/) (section *"Lightweight, portable projects"*).

Related : [How to use namespaces with import in TypeScript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37565709/how-to-use-namespaces-with-import-in-typescript) and [Modules vs. Namespaces: What is the correct way to organize a large typescript project?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39827281/modules-vs-namespaces-what-is-the-correct-way-to-organize-a-large-typescript-p/39827997) .

Comment: Using TypeScript in a context of GAS (Google Apps Script) project, this is the way to go. There is no modules import-export syntax allowed. Namespace are the only way to be able to split code into multiple files.